# Metric space $(X,d)$ and restricted metric space $(M,d_M)$ . Show the following statement and find counterexample for the second one.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let ($X,d$) be a metric space and $ M \subset X $. Let $d_M$ be the restricted metric. ($M,d_M$) is a metric space.

Show:

Let $M$ be open in ($X,d$). Then $A \subset M$ open in ($M,d_M$) if and only if A open in ($X,d$).

Find an example:

$M \subset X$ closed in $(X,d)$, but $(M,d_M)$ not complete.

Attempt: "$\Rightarrow$" So $A$ is open in $M$. For $a \in A$ there is a $\varepsilon_a > 0$ with $ U_{\varepsilon_a,d_M}(a) \subset A $.

$M$ is open in $(X,d)$. Since $ a \in A $ we know that $ a \in M$. We find $ \varepsilon_b > 0 $ with $ U_{\varepsilon_b,d} (a) \subset M$. Here I need your help.
For there other direction we know that $ U_{\varepsilon,d}(a) \subset A $ then we could consider the intersection of $U_{\varepsilon,d}(a)$ and $M$?

I already showed: $ A \subset M$ open in $(M,d_M)$ if and only if there is a open set $ B \subset X$ in $(X,d)$ with $A = B \cap M $. Maybe this could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is open in $X$ then for all $a\in A$ there is a ball with center in $a$ and contained in $A$. In particular contained in $M$. Therefore, $A$ is open in $M$.

Assume $A$ is open in $M$. Then, for every $a\in A$ there is a ball $U_r$ with radius $r$ with center in $a$ contained in $M$. Since $A$ is open in $M$ there is a ball $U_s$ such that $U_s\cap M\subset A$. Consider $V=U_{\min(r,s)}$. Since $V\subset U_r$, then $V\cap M=V$. Since $V\subset U_s$ then $V\subset A$.

For the other exercise take $X=\{1/n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $M=X$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the finite intersection of open sets is open again:\
Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $A,B$ be open in $X$. Without limiting the generality assume $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ (because the empty set is open anyway).
Let $a\in A\cap B$, then $\exists \epsilon_A,\epsilon_B>0$ such that $B_{\epsilon_{A}}(a)\subset A$ and $B_{\epsilon_{B}}(a)\subset B$.\
Now $B_{min\{\epsilon_A,\epsilon_B\}}(a)$ is contained in $A\cap B$.